# Подскажите по регулярке файла по средством bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Есть файл key.txt. Его содержимое:

`["Iufoos5Eboh2iuphi4jeid4oB4ohco", "Zaing4megooTeiD5puwo6ohDei1ahw", "gei9ohngiecai5oShuim1vohVei1Th", "laHa2aa8Ao8uodoog3aici5Ees0quo", "dooWia8eew3zai8ohquaihecochigh"]`

Регуляркой прохожусь по файлу

grep "[^.]" key.txt | sed 's/[][]//g' | tr -d " | tr "," "\n"

Вывод:

```
Iufoos5Eboh2iuphi4jeid4oB4ohco
 Zaing4megooTeiD5puwo6ohDei1ahw
 gei9ohngiecai5oShuim1vohVei1Th
 laHa2aa8Ao8uodoog3aici5Ees0quo
 dooWia8eew3zai8ohquaihecochigh
```

Почему со второй строки пробел и что я делаю не так (ось - Ubunta 18.04).
Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сделать одним вызовом *AWK*:

```sh
$ awk -F '[][ ,"]+' '{ for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) { print $i; } }' key.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep "[^.]" key.txt | sed 's/[] []//g' | tr -d " | tr "," "\n"
```

пробел в `sed` добавить, а лучше так:

```
grep "[^.]" key.txt | sed 's/[] "[]//g' | tr "," "\n"
```